# Refresh IBOutlet appearance on parent view after popup segue is 'dismissed'

Tags: ios, swift3, segue

I have a small app that consists of a main screen and a 'settings' screen (which is a popup modal). I used an iOS segue to load the settings popup.

On the settings popup you essentially set the background to light or dark but I'm not sure how to load my 'makeScreenLight' method after the modal has been dismissed.

Do I use **viewDidAppear**, and how do I call it?

Or do I use it with the dismiss method before or while the popup is dismissed:

```
@IBAction func BackFromSettings(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: How do you present yout popup modal VC? Can you past this part of your code?

Comment: I didn't use code - I ctrl dragged the button to the segue controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to achieve this, including global state, notifications, and delegation. I'll give an example using delegation:

First we'll create a protocol that defines the delegation relationship.

```
protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func settingsUpdated(light: Bool)
}
```

Next, we'll make the first view controller conform to this new protocol, and implement its one method. We will also make sure to set the second view controller's delegate to the first view controller when we segue.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, SecondViewControllerDelegate {

    func settingsUpdated(light: Bool) {
        // modify the UI here
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let secondViewController = segue.destination as? SecondViewController else { return }
        secondViewController.delegate = self
    }

}
```

When an action occurs in the second view controller (in this case a switch being pressed), we can call the method on our delegate. This will make the change in the first view controller.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: SecondViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UISwitch) {
       delegate?.settingsUpdated(light: sender.isOn)
    }

    @IBAction func backFromSettings(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```